# push javascript array through jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I need to pass in a javascript array into jquery but my code is only returning [object object]

```
$( "#enviar" ).click(function() {
        var data = {};
        var i = 0;
        var u = -1;

        $.each($('.ui'), function() { 
            data[i] = this.value; 
            i++;
        });

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "send_car.php",
                data: "photo="+data+"&u="+u,
                success: function(data){

                }//end success  
            })//end ajax submit*/   
});
```

console log is showing the array

```
Object {0="d-170", 1="d-171"}
```

but the data is being pass as [object object]

ui class is a hidden input with the same name and different values.

I have read various post and tried with serialize but I get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're concatenating an object and a string, but jQuery supports passing in arrays and objects directly, so just use that

```
$.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: "send_car.php",
      data: { 
          photo : data, 
          u     : u
      },
      success: function(data){

      }
});
```

what you're doing is

```
var obj  = {key : "value"};

var data = "test" + obj;
```

and when you add an object to a string, they both become strings, and the string representation of an object is `[object, Object]`.